# sum of duplicates in array php

Tags: php, arrays

Im not sure what function to search for in regards to this so cant seem to help myself. Seems like an obvious problem really.
I have an array, and where I have duplicate keys, I wish to add the values. e.g:

This is a section of my array.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 21.41 KB
        [outputAvg] => 22.03 KB
        [date] => 2011-08-01
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 182.63 KB
        [outputAvg] => 186.05 KB
        [date] => 2011-08-01
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 182.63 KB
        [outputAvg] => 186.05 KB
        [date] => 2011-08-02
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 4.84 MB
        [outputAvg] => 4.93 MB
        [date] => 2011-08-03
    )
```

All I wish to do is, say where the date key of the array is the same (e.g. here 2011-08-01) I want to show this date once, but with combined values of the duplicate item....?

e.g

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 204.04 KB
        [outputAvg] => 208.08 KB
        [date] => 2011-08-01
    )


[2] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 182.63 KB
        [outputAvg] => 186.05 KB
        [date] => 2011-08-02
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [inputAvg] => 4.84 MB
        [outputAvg] => 4.93 MB
        [date] => 2011-08-03
    )
```

Comment: Combained?? added or concatenated ??

Comment: sorry. added. ignore the MB KB, but sum of the two values...?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649500/php-splitting-arrays-into-groups-based-on-one-fields-value

Comment: Best solution for you could be checking for duplicates right when you add element to array. If the key already exists, it will add the values, if not it will add new key to array.

Comment: @mrsorbose Is this data coming from database? If so you could use `group by`. Not a solution but this is db work, IMO (if data comes from db of course).

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: it is origionally DB stuff, but gets altered loads before this array in php.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<?php

$array  = array(Array("inputAvg" => 21.41,"outputAvg" => 22.03,"date" => "2011-08-01"),
                Array("inputAvg" => 182.63,"outputAvg" => 186.05,"date" => "2011-08-01" ),
                Array("inputAvg" => 182.63, "outputAvg" => 186.05,"date" => "2011-08-02")
                );

$res  = array();
foreach($array as $vals){
    if(array_key_exists($vals['date'],$res)){
        $res[$vals['date']]['inputAvg']    += $vals['inputAvg'];
        $res[$vals['date']]['outputAvg']   += $vals['outputAvg'];
        $res[$vals['date']]['date']        = $vals['date'];
    }
    else{
        $res[$vals['date']]  = $vals;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);

?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [2011-08-01] => Array
        (
            [inputAvg] => 204.04
            [outputAvg] => 208.08
            [date] => 2011-08-01
        )

    [2011-08-02] => Array
        (
            [inputAvg] => 182.63
            [outputAvg] => 186.05
            [date] => 2011-08-02
        )

)
```

Comment: +1 Superb bro..Saw two questions where you figured out great logic today..Amaging..Had tp praise u..I too got to solutions but not as quick as u!! IIt(ian)?

Comment: @SankalpMishra : Thanks buddy...but not iit (ian) because not tried ;)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, $data has all data that you want to process on

```
$dateArray = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value['date'], $dateArray)){
        $newArray[$value['date']]['inputAvg'] = $value['inputAvg'] + $newArray[$value['date']]['inputAvg'];
        $newArray[$value['date']]['outputAvg'] = $value['outputAvg'] + $newArray[$value['date']]['outputAvg'];
    }
    else{
        $dateArray[] = $value['date'];
        $newArray[$value['date']] = $value;
    }
}
```

But remember, that addition will just add your averages and not show KB/MB in the end. You will have to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ;

```
$new = array() ;

foreach ($stats as $traffic){
  $key = $traffic['date'] ;

  if (isset($new[$key])){
    if ($new[$key]['date'] === $traffic['date']){
      $new[$key]['inputAvg'] += $traffic['inputAvg'] ;
      $new[$key]['outputAvg'] += $traffic['outputAvg'] ;
    }
  } else {
    $new[$key] = $traffic ;
  }
}

var_dump($new) ;
```

Edited TYPO, so it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that takes into account KB, MB and GB

Function to get absolute value from KB, MB and GB

```
function mul($unit) {
  $mul = 1;
  switch($unit) {
    case 'GB': $mul *= 1000;
    case 'MB': $mul *= 1000;
    case 'KB': $mul *= 1000;
  }
  return $mul;
}
```

Function to make a string from number, divided by G, M or K and add postfix

```
function demul($val) {
  $units = array('GB','MB','KB');
  $unit = '  ';
  $m = 1000000000;
  for ($i=0 ; $i<3 ; $i++) {
    if ($val >= $m) {
      $val /= $m;
      $unit = $units[$i];
      break;
    }
    $m /= 1000;
  }
  return number_format($val, 2) . ' ' . $unit;
}
```

Main loop, `$arr` is the original array ; fill `dates` array with summed data

```
$dates = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $a) {
  $d = $a['date'];
  $i = explode(' ', $a['inputAvg']);
  $o = explode(' ', $a['outputAvg']);
  $in  = $i[0] * mul($i[1]);
  $out = $o[0] * mul($o[1]);

  if ( ! isset($dates[$d])) {
    $dates[$d] = array($in, $out);
  }
  else {
    $dates[$d][0] += $in;
    $dates[$d][1] += $out;
  }
}
```

Make `result` array based on original format

```
$result = array();
$n = 1;
foreach ($dates as $d => $a) {
  $result[$n++] = array('date' => $d, 'inputAvg' => demul($a[0]), 'outputAvg' => demul($a[1]));
}
```

Print result

```
print_r($result);
```

Given the data

```
$arr = array(
'1' => Array
    (
        'inputAvg' => '21.41 KB',
        'outputAvg' => '22.03 KB',
        'date' => '2011-08-01',
    ),

'2' => Array
    (
        'inputAvg' => '182.63 KB',
        'outputAvg' => '186.05 KB',
        'date' => '2011-08-01',
    ),

'3' => Array
    (
        'inputAvg' => '182.63 KB',
        'outputAvg' => '186.05 KB',
        'date' => '2011-08-02',
    ),

'4' => Array
    (
        'inputAvg' => '4.84 MB',
        'outputAvg' => '4.93 MB',
        'date' => '2011-08-03',
    )
);
```

It gives the output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2011-08-01
            [inputAvg] => 204.04 KB
            [outputAvg] => 208.08 KB
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2011-08-02
            [inputAvg] => 182.63 KB
            [outputAvg] => 186.05 KB
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2011-08-03
            [inputAvg] => 4.84 MB
            [outputAvg] => 4.93 MB
        )

)
```