# Pass an array through js in its pure form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, send

I have a form with three input fields: an array, a date column, and a cash column. I am using the code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958176/15368688 to get the sum of the duplicates, however I am getting an error because my array is being passed as a string. How to fix it?

JS to submit data from the form

```
$('#get_result').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/array_to_table_ajax.php",
            data: { 
                col_date: $("#col_date").val(),
                cash: $("#cash").val(),
                array: $("#array").val(),
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

AJAX

```
$array  = (array)$_POST['array'];
$date  = $_POST['col_date'];
$cash = $_POST['cash'];

$res  = array();
foreach($array as $vals){
    if(array_key_exists($vals[$date],$res)){
        $res[$vals[$date]][$cash]    += $vals[$cash];
        $res[$vals[$date]][$date]        = $vals[$date];
    }
    else{
        $res[$vals[$date]]  = $vals;
    }
}

echo "ARRAY: ". var_dump($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Throws an error and refers to the line:
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Date column' in

```
if(array_key_exists($vals[$date],$res)){
```

Also var_dump says what $array is not an array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(344) "array ( 0 => array ( 'Date' => '7/1/21', 'Sum' => '123', ), 1 => array ( 'Date' => '7/1/21', 'Sum' => '321', ), 2 => array ( 'Date' => '7/2/21', 'Sum' => '111', ), 3 => array ( 'Date' => '7/2/21', 'Sum' => '112', ), 4 => array ( 'Date' => '7/3/21', 'Sum' => '555', ), )" }
```

Edit: I just send the php array directly without converting to js because the columns are always changing.

Comment: Also be aware that a PHP array is not the same as a JS array. Look into using JSON instead?

Comment: Would be useful to see how the string arrives to the JavaScript. It is most useful to use JSON

Comment: An input field can't contain an array. The value of an input field is always a string.

Comment: I just send the php array directly without converting to js because the columns are always changing.

Comment: It looks like you've put the results of `print_r()` into the `array` input. This can't be parsed as an array.