# How to sum an associative array in laravel by there keys?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array which will have an SKU number, it can be repeated so want to sum of that SKU qty at once and insert in DB table.

```
`$data = array(
 0 => array(
 '0' => 'SKU',
 '1' => 'header1',
 '2' => 'header2',
 '3' => 'qty'
),
1 => array(
 '0' => 'SKU-abc',
 '1' => 50,
 '2' => 0,
 '3' => 50
),
2 => array(
'0' => 'SKU-pqr',
'1' => 50,
'2' => 0,
'3' => 50
),
3 => array(
'0' => 'SKU-abc',
'1' => 0,
'2' => 25,
'3' => 25

)`
```

How can i sum the same sku as index 1 and 3 have and remove the 1st index?

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking, its best to assume we cannot read your mind and we are not looking over your shoulder. Explain specifically, with examples or even diagrams where necessary

Comment: You can check the answer on this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958176/3094795)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the solution on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958176/3094795)

here is how to do it:

```php
$data = array(
 0 => array(
 '0' => 'SKU',
 '1' => 'header1',
 '2' => 'header2',
 '3' => 'qty'
),
1 => array(
 '0' => 'SKU-abc',
 '1' => 50,
 '2' => 0,
 '3' => 50
),
2 => array(
'0' => 'SKU-pqr',
'1' => 50,
'2' => 0,
'3' => 50
),
3 => array(
'0' => 'SKU-abc',
'1' => 0,
'2' => 25,
'3' => 25
));

$res  = array();
foreach($data as $vals){
    if(array_key_exists($vals['0'],$res)){
        $res[$vals['0']]['1']   += $vals['1'];
        $res[$vals['0']]['2']   += $vals['2'];
        $res[$vals['0']]['3']   += $vals['3'];
        $res[$vals['0']]['0']    = $vals['0'];
    }
    else{
        $res[$vals['0']]  = $vals;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

The result is:

```php
Array
(
    [SKU] => Array
        (
            [0] => SKU
            [1] => header1
            [2] => header2
            [3] => qty
        )

    [SKU-abc] => Array
        (
            [0] => SKU-abc
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 25
            [3] => 75
        )

    [SKU-pqr] => Array
        (
            [0] => SKU-pqr
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 50
        )

)
```