# php array how to remove duplicate, combine and plus value in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i wondering how to combine array also make some value turn to unique and plus some value to make a total:

This is my json encode code if some want to try test it.

```
{ "error": "", "message": "", "response": { "order_list": [ { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQB9BL", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 7001, "item_name": "smartwatch md41", "item_sku": "smartwatchmd41", "model_id": 74599279361, "model_name": "smartwatch md41,Blue", "model_sku": "smblue", "model_quantity_purchased": 1 }, { "item_id": 7001, "item_name": "smartwatch md41", "item_sku": "smartwatchmd41", "model_id": 74599279362, "model_name": "smartwatch md41,Red", "model_sku": "smred", "model_quantity_purchased": 2 } ] }, { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQBGBA", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 7001, "item_name": "smartwatch md41", "item_sku": "smartwatchmd41", "model_id": 74599279362, "model_name": "smartwatch md41,Red", "model_sku": "smred", "model_quantity_purchased": 3 } ] }, { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQB9RT", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 8009, "item_name": "Basket", "item_sku": "basket", "model_id": 74599279812, "model_name": "Basket BiG,XL", "model_sku": "basketxl", "model_quantity_purchased": 5 } ] }, { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQB9GY", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 8009, "item_name": "Basket", "item_sku": "basket", "model_id": 74599279812, "model_name": "Basket BiG,XL", "model_sku": "basketxl", "model_quantity_purchased": 2 } ] }, { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQB9BA", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 8009, "item_name": "Basket", "item_sku": "basket", "model_id": 74599279812, "model_name": "Basket M,M", "model_sku": "basketm", "model_quantity_purchased": 2 } ] }, { "order_sn" : "220703FTRQB9JW", "item_list": [ { "item_id": 7001, "item_name": "smartwatch md41", "item_sku": "smartwatchmd41", "model_id": 74599279361, "model_name": "smartwatch md41,Blue", "model_sku": "smblue", "model_quantity_purchased": 2 } ] } ] }, "request_id": "3f5d35090159078fd0a2e1602ae9f4f5" }
```

Below is the output from json

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [message] => 
    [response] => Array
        (
            [order_list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQB9BL
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 7001
                                            [item_name] => smartwatch md41
                                            [item_sku] => smartwatchmd41
                                            [model_id] => 74599279361
                                            [model_name] => smartwatch md41,Blue
                                            [model_sku] => smblue
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 1
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 7001
                                            [item_name] => smartwatch md41
                                            [item_sku] => smartwatchmd41
                                            [model_id] => 74599279362
                                            [model_name] => smartwatch md41,Red
                                            [model_sku] => smred
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQBGBA
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 7001
                                            [item_name] => smartwatch md41
                                            [item_sku] => smartwatchmd41
                                            [model_id] => 74599279362
                                            [model_name] => smartwatch md41,Red
                                            [model_sku] => smred
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQB9RT
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 8009
                                            [item_name] => Basket
                                            [item_sku] => basket
                                            [model_id] => 74599279812
                                            [model_name] => Basket BiG,XL
                                            [model_sku] => basketxl
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 5
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQB9GY
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 8009
                                            [item_name] => Basket
                                            [item_sku] => basket
                                            [model_id] => 74599279812
                                            [model_name] => Basket BiG,XL
                                            [model_sku] => basketxl
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQB9BA
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 8009
                                            [item_name] => Basket
                                            [item_sku] => basket
                                            [model_id] => 74599279812
                                            [model_name] => Basket M,M
                                            [model_sku] => basketm
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [order_sn] => 220703FTRQB9JW
                            [item_list] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [item_id] => 7001
                                            [item_name] => smartwatch md41
                                            [item_sku] => smartwatchmd41
                                            [model_id] => 74599279361
                                            [model_name] => smartwatch md41,Blue
                                            [model_sku] => smblue
                                            [model_quantity_purchased] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [request_id] => 3f5d35090159078fd0a2e1602ae9f4f5
)
```

What i expect it should be result like this:

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olhQW.png)

This API result i got from API so i need to to build my picklist item code for my shop.
i really hope someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of duplicates in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957901/sum-of-duplicates-in-array-php)

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz i got that one but its not working for multi filter. you can see at here https://i.imgur.com/UbBD1mN.png . Each Model SKU only got one list only also i dont know how to put order SN inside it. My code is here: https://pastebin.com/diBG2ES2

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz i got that one but its not working for multi filter. you can see at here https://i.imgur.com/UbBD1mN.png . Each Model SKU only got one list only also i dont know how to put order SN inside it. My code is here: https://pastebin.com/diBG2ES2